# Difficulty authenticating to CouchDB

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, couchdb

I have a couch server running and I am attempting to access it from a web application served from port 80. I am having difficulty authenticating.

The code I am using to test is:

```
var host = 'http://localhost:5984'
var url = host + "/wells/"
var username = 'will'
var password = 'secret'

// Succeeds
$.post(
  host + "/_session",
  { name: username, password: password },
  function() {
    console.log( 'cookie', document.cookie ) // doesn't include AuthSession
    $.get( url ) // Fails 401 unauthorized
  }
)

var hostParts = host.split( '://' )
var hostWithAuth = hostParts[1] + "://" + username + ":" + password + "@" + hostParts[2]
$.get( hostWithAuth ) // Fails unauthorized, credentials removed from url

// Fails unauthorized
$.ajax( {
  url: url,
  username: username,
  password: password,
  success: function() {
    console.log( arguments )
  },
  xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Basic " + btoa( username + ":" + password )
  }
} )

// Fails unauthorized
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
xmlHttp.open( 'GET', url, false, username, password )
xmlHttp.send( null )
console.log( xmlHttp.responseText )
```

It seems as though my credentials are being removed when I try to pass them in the url and the cookie isn't sent to the server when using sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Your requests fails because of [Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) since you made AJAX request to url with different port (not 80). You need to setup [CORS](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/config/http.html#cross-origin-resource-sharing) correctly to let your requests succeeded.

P.S. And why not to use [jquery.couch.js](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/master/share/www/script/jquery.couch.js) as client library instead of own $.ajax calls? It handles a lot of useful bits and provides nicer API.