# Fetch CouchDB to authenticate using cookie

Tags: cookies, fetch, couchdb

I'm trying to authenticate against couchdb using [this documentation](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/server/authn.html)

When I do

```
# first request
const url = 'http://localhost:5984/_session'
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body : JSON.stringify({
        "name": "my_username",
        "password": "my_password"
    }),
}).then( data => {
    console.log(data)
}).catch(e => {
    console.log('Error', e)
})
```

If one of my_username or my_password IS NOT right i get:

```
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 401
statusText: "Unauthorized"
type: "cors"
url: "http://localhost:5984/_session"
```

which is fine.

But, if one of my_username or my_password IS right i get:

```
body: ReadableStream
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "cors"
url: "http://localhost:5984/_session"
```

instead of

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Content-Length: 43
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Mon, 03 Dec 2012 01:23:14 GMT
Server: CouchDB (Erlang/OTP)
Set-Cookie: AuthSession=cm9vdDo1MEJCRkYwMjq0LO0ylOIwShrgt8y-UkhI-c6BGw; Version=1; Path=/; 
HttpOnly

{"ok":true,"name":"root","roles":["_admin"]}  // <-- i expect that
```

And no cookie set.

I also tried curl, it works :

```
> curl http://localhost:5984/_session
{"ok":true,"userCtx":{"name":null,"roles":[]},"info":{"authentication_handlers": 
["cookie","default"]}}

> curl -X POST http://localhost:5984/_session -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"my_username","password":"my_password"}'
{"ok":true,"name":"my_username","roles":["_admin"]}
```

But I need it to work in a react app, from http:localhost:3000

[Maybe it's CORS related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23682143/difficulty-authenticating-to-couchdb)? I enabled CORS in CouchDB settings.

How can i modify the first request in order to get the user object for the name/password supplied?

Comment: Try enabling CORS in couchdb and add {credentials: 'include'} to the fetch call to get the data. That worked for me. I didn't need to get the session cookie.

Answer (score -2):

I think Authentication Set-Cookie produce by backend server not by front end. So you need backend like Node.js to get cookie and then get it again from your front end.

Comment: CouchDB is the back end in this case.

Comment: 1. I mean HTTP ONLY (Secure) cookies cannot be accessed in JavaScript. If you try to read some token, etc from a secure cookie (Set-Cookie) it's not going to work.

2. Cross-domain cookies cannot be accessed. In case you are building a single page application (SPA like ReactJS) and your server is on a different domain. You cannot access the cookies on your SPA. The 'withCredentials' flag will just make sure that the network calls made include the cookies and accept any incoming cookies.